# How to straighten out curved fingers in blender?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

For these Call of duty models the fingers are bent or curved and I need them to be straight. I've tried to do it manually, pose it etc but they deform in every possible way and its not looking good. How should I go about this?

[image]

[image]

So basically I need to go from the curved fingers to the 2nd picture straight fingers. I need to align the first picture model to the second one as accurate as possible. I tried going into the armature and pose mode and pose the bones to bend in a way so it matches the 2nd one but they deform wrong as soon as I bend them. I tried copy rotation as well but they still bend in a weird way. I tried pose brush as well recently but it just wouldnt do it properly. Can someone help me?

Here is my project's link:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. please show some screenshots of what you have tried.

Comment: Hello, you could try to do it with its armature if he has one, or use the Pose brush in Sculpt mode, it allows to bend shape (or unbend in your case)

Comment: hello. Well when you say armature, do you mean the skeleton? Cause there is and that is how i tried to pose it in pose mode. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Armatures are Blender's version of skeletons.

Comment: To "straighten fingers" can mean different things (aligned with world axes, straight from parent, with or without splaying, ...). It depends on what purpose you need that. There is no particular technique of strengthening fingers, you could just go in edit mode and move every vertex one by one if you want. If you have an armature, it should be one of the easiest ways to do so. Please [edit] your post to precisely explain what you need, why, what you tried, how it didn't work, and consider uploading your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see in which way your bones "*bend in a weird way*". I can rotate them just fine.

[image]

You could literally just rotate all the bones manually and eyeball their alignment. Just set your Transform Orientation to make your rotation gizmo align with the bones.

[image]

But you can also speed things up a bit by using constraints temporarily.

Within a chain of bones that should be aligned, like a finger, you have a bone at the start of the chain, one at the end, and maybe a few intermediates. If the rig was built somewhat correctly, and each bone of the isolated chain is parent from each other, you could use a bunch of ***Copy Rotation*** constraints to align all the bones of the chain align to the start bone of the chain.

[image]

1. In Pose mode, select the start bone, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the end bone
2. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to add a ***Copy Rotation*** constraint on the end bone, with the start bone as target.
3. Select all the intermediates bones if you have some (fingers usually have one for the thumb and two for the other fingers), then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the end bone of the chain.
4. Go in the menu Pose > Constraints > Copy Constraints to Selected Bones.

You can quickly do fingers like this:

[image]

Probably also arms and legs if you need to.
Once you are done, you probably don't want to keep the constraints forever. You can use the menu Pose > Constraints > Clear Pose Constraints or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, which will apply the constraints and keep the bones transforms. From there, you can set a keyframe with <kbd>I</kbd>, or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> > Apply As Rest Pose.

Comment: oh thank you so much the helped a lot!!